# Return the length of a filtered Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this if statement that returns only the results of the array that correspond with the user input. In other words, a search bar for the array.

```
var filter = userInput.value.toUpperCase();
for (var i = 0; i < myArrayElements.length; i++) {
    if (myArrayElements.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1)  {
        myArrayElements[i].style.display = 'list-item';
    } else {
        myArrayElements[i].style.display = 'none';      
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how I can return the length of the filtered array. Plus I would like to use that length in the global scope.

I tried this inside the if statement :

```
var arrayLength = myArrayElements[i].length;
return arrayLength;
```

and

```
console.log(myArrayElements[i].length);
```

But no success either : the console returns an error.

***Edit***: *Nina Scholz* answer returns the length of the array properly and the example given is awesome, but the other answers with .filter() are well worth taking into consideration, thanks to you all!

Comment: Where is your filtered array?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your if statement doesnt return anything. The length of `myArrayElements[i]` isnt anything becuase thats a reference to something in the array not to the array.

Comment: btw, you are not filtering something, but iterating and assigning.

Comment: try `console.log(myArrayElements.length);`

Comment: my array is a list of li's that are built like this: `<ul class="masterUL">
        <li class="myArrayElements">
            <div class="Details"> </div> </li>..... </ul>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a variable for the count.

```
var filter = userInput.value.toUpperCase(),
    count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < myArrayElements.length; i++) {
    if (myArrayElements[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1)  {
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ only if that is really a string!!!
        myArrayElements[i].style.display = 'list-item';
        count++;
    } else {
        myArrayElements[i].style.display = 'none';      
    }
}
```

Working example:

```js
function find() {    
    var filter = document.getElementById('search').value.toUpperCase(),
        count = 0,
        myArrayElements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');        

    for (var i = 0; i < myArrayElements.length; i++) {
         if (myArrayElements[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1)  {
              myArrayElements[i].style.display = 'list-item';
              count++;
         } else {
             myArrayElements[i].style.display = 'none';      
         }
    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

```html
<input id="search" > <button onclick="find()">find</button>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test-case</li>
<li>42</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this technically answers OP's question, this is still invalid code for a number of reasons. 1) array prototype does not have a `toUpperCase` method. 2) using a string to filter what appears to be dom nodes will not work (without first extracting the text from the dom nodes)

Comment: @Damon I think given the way that OP asked the question that its a fair assumption that `filter` can equal an element of the array.

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption given OP is using a string method on `filter` and ... also the same method on an array. I wouldn't make any assumptions about the validity of the code in that case.

Comment: @Damon sure you cant make assumptions about the validity of the code, but within the context of the question I think its a fair assumption and given the answers to the question it looks like Im not alone.

Comment: @Craicerjack Let me rephrase - the code IS invalid, and OP should know that. As this answer has been edited to cover my comments, I have no issues with it now. I still think it's important to post valid code when answering. If OP's code is invalid beyond a shadow of a doubt (which it is), that should be pointed out.

Comment: @Damon absolutely, and Im not in any way criticising you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`filter` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

```
var newArray = myArrayElements.filter(function(value, index, array) {
  return value.toUpperCase() === filter;
});
var newArrayLength = newArray.length;
```

It has been pointed out (and I saw this myself, but answered anyway as it answered the question asked) that this doesnt take into consideration the logic within the loop. This could be fixed by having all elements in `myArrayElements` as `display:none;` as default and then use:

```
var newArray.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
  value.style.display = 'list-item';
});
```

or you could use `forEach()` from the off:

```
var filter = userInput.value.toUpperCase(),
    count = 0;

myArrayElements.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
  (value.toUpperCase() === filter) ? value.style.display = 'list-item' : value.style.display = 'none';
  count ++;
});
```

Comment: The code posted by OP does something inside of the if and else condtion. So the code needs to do something even if the records dont match with the input...

Comment: yeah, but you could set all elements in `myArrayElements` to none style and then just the element in `newArray` to the other style. Answering the question asked. Also its good to get introduced to different ways to do things

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.filter()` function to perform the style change and get a filtered array in one swoop.

```
var filter = userInput.value.toUpperCase(),
filterFunc = function(element) {
  if (element === filter) {
    element.style.display = 'list-item';
    return true;
  }
  else {
    element.style.display = 'none';
    return false;
  }
}

var filteredLength = myArrayElements.filter(filterFunc).length;
```